# IndexError: pop from an empty deque while using pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to learn how to use mongo and got this error. The password is meant to start with an exclamation mark, but I change the actual password. Here's the code and error:

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
import dns.resolver
dns.resolver.default_resolver=dns.resolver.Resolver(configure=False)
dns.resolver.default_resolver.nameservers=['8.8.8.8']

cluster = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://gabriel:%33%password@cluster1.ez4er.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority")

db = cluster["gabdatabase"]

collection = db["learningmongo"]

print(cluster.list_database_names())
```

```
Desktop % /usr/local/bin/python /Users/Gu/Desktop/python/py2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 1394, in _get_socket
    sock_info = self.sockets.popleft()
IndexError: pop from an empty deque

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Gu/Desktop/python/py2.py", line 15, in <module>
    collection.insert_one(post)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 705, in insert_one
    self._insert(document,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 620, in _insert
    return self._insert_one(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 609, in _insert_one
    self.__database.client._retryable_write(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1552, in _retryable_write
    return self._retry_with_session(retryable, func, s, None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1438, in _retry_with_session
    return self._retry_internal(retryable, func, session, bulk)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1462, in _retry_internal
    with self._get_socket(server, session) as sock_info:
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 117, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1308, in _get_socket
    with server.get_socket(
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 117, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 1331, in get_socket
    sock_info = self._get_socket(all_credentials)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 1397, in _get_socket
    sock_info = self.connect(all_credentials)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 1297, in connect
    sock_info.check_auth(all_credentials)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 820, in check_auth
    self.authenticate(credentials)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 837, in authenticate
    auth.authenticate(credentials, self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/auth.py", line 672, in authenticate
    auth_func(credentials, sock_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/auth.py", line 590, in _authenticate_default
    return _authenticate_scram(credentials, sock_info, 'SCRAM-SHA-1')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/auth.py", line 333, in _authenticate_scram
    res = sock_info.command(source, cmd)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 710, in command
    return command(self, dbname, spec, secondary_ok,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/network.py", line 158, in command
    helpers._check_command_response(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/helpers.py", line 167, in _check_command_response
    raise OperationFailure(errmsg, code, response, max_wire_version)
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: bad auth : Authentication failed., full error: {'ok': 0, 'errmsg': 'bad auth : Authentication failed.', 'code': 8000, 'codeName': 'AtlasError'}
Gu@21emashmore21-971 Desktop % /usr/local/bin/python /Users/Gu/Desktop/python/py2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 1394, in _get_socket
    sock_info = self.sockets.popleft()
IndexError: pop from an empty deque

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Gu/Desktop/python/py2.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(cluster.list_database_names())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 2037, in list_database_names
    for doc in self.list_databases(session, nameOnly=True)]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 2018, in list_databases
    res = admin._retryable_read_command(cmd, session=session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/database.py", line 770, in _retryable_read_command
    return self.__client._retryable_read(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1518, in _retryable_read
    with self._secondaryok_for_server(
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 117, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1371, in _secondaryok_for_server
    with self._get_socket(server, session) as sock_info:
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 117, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1308, in _get_socket
    with server.get_socket(
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 117, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 1331, in get_socket
    sock_info = self._get_socket(all_credentials)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 1397, in _get_socket
    sock_info = self.connect(all_credentials)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 1297, in connect
    sock_info.check_auth(all_credentials)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 820, in check_auth
    self.authenticate(credentials)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 837, in authenticate
    auth.authenticate(credentials, self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/auth.py", line 672, in authenticate
    auth_func(credentials, sock_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/auth.py", line 590, in _authenticate_default
    return _authenticate_scram(credentials, sock_info, 'SCRAM-SHA-1')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/auth.py", line 333, in _authenticate_scram
    res = sock_info.command(source, cmd)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 710, in command
    return command(self, dbname, spec, secondary_ok,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/network.py", line 158, in command
    helpers._check_command_response(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/helpers.py", line 167, in _check_command_response
    raise OperationFailure(errmsg, code, response, max_wire_version)
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: bad auth : Authentication failed., full error: {'ok': 0, 'errmsg': 'bad auth : Authentication failed.', 'code': 8000, 'codeName': 'AtlasError'}
Gu@21emashmore21-971 Desktop % /usr/local/bin/python /Users/Gu/Desktop/python/py2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 1394, in _get_socket
    sock_info = self.sockets.popleft()
IndexError: pop from an empty deque

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Gu/Desktop/python/py2.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(cluster.list_database_names())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 2037, in list_database_names
    for doc in self.list_databases(session, nameOnly=True)]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 2018, in list_databases
    res = admin._retryable_read_command(cmd, session=session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/database.py", line 770, in _retryable_read_command
    return self.__client._retryable_read(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1518, in _retryable_read
    with self._secondaryok_for_server(
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 117, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1371, in _secondaryok_for_server
    with self._get_socket(server, session) as sock_info:
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 117, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1308, in _get_socket
    with server.get_socket(
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 117, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 1331, in get_socket
    sock_info = self._get_socket(all_credentials)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 1397, in _get_socket
    sock_info = self.connect(all_credentials)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 1297, in connect
    sock_info.check_auth(all_credentials)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 820, in check_auth
    self.authenticate(credentials)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 837, in authenticate
    auth.authenticate(credentials, self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/auth.py", line 672, in authenticate
    auth_func(credentials, sock_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/auth.py", line 590, in _authenticate_default
    return _authenticate_scram(credentials, sock_info, 'SCRAM-SHA-1')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/auth.py", line 333, in _authenticate_scram
    res = sock_info.command(source, cmd)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 710, in command
    return command(self, dbname, spec, secondary_ok,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/network.py", line 158, in command
    helpers._check_command_response(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/helpers.py", line 167, in _check_command_response
    raise OperationFailure(errmsg, code, response, max_wire_version)
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: bad auth : Authentication failed., full error: {'ok': 0, 'errmsg': 'bad auth : Authentication failed.', 'code': 8000, 'codeName': 'AtlasError'}
Gu@21emashmore21-971 Desktop % /usr/local/bin/python /Users/Gu/Desktop/python/py2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 1394, in _get_socket
    sock_info = self.sockets.popleft()
IndexError: pop from an empty deque

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Gu/Desktop/python/py2.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(cluster.list_database_names())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 2037, in list_database_names
    for doc in self.list_databases(session, nameOnly=True)]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 2018, in list_databases
    res = admin._retryable_read_command(cmd, session=session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/database.py", line 770, in _retryable_read_command
    return self.__client._retryable_read(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1518, in _retryable_read
    with self._secondaryok_for_server(
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 117, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1371, in _secondaryok_for_server
    with self._get_socket(server, session) as sock_info:
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 117, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1308, in _get_socket
    with server.get_socket(
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 117, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 1331, in get_socket
    sock_info = self._get_socket(all_credentials)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 1397, in _get_socket
    sock_info = self.connect(all_credentials)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 1297, in connect
    sock_info.check_auth(all_credentials)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 820, in check_auth
    self.authenticate(credentials)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 837, in authenticate
    auth.authenticate(credentials, self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/auth.py", line 672, in authenticate
    auth_func(credentials, sock_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/auth.py", line 590, in _authenticate_default
    return _authenticate_scram(credentials, sock_info, 'SCRAM-SHA-1')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/auth.py", line 333, in _authenticate_scram
    res = sock_info.command(source, cmd)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 710, in command
    return command(self, dbname, spec, secondary_ok,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/network.py", line 158, in command
    helpers._check_command_response(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/helpers.py", line 167, in _check_command_response
    raise OperationFailure(errmsg, code, response, max_wire_version)
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: bad auth : Authentication failed., full error: {'ok': 0, 'errmsg': 'bad auth : Authentication failed.', 'code': 8000, 'codeName': 'AtlasError'}
Gu@21emashmore21-971 Desktop % /usr/local/bin/python /Users/Gu/Desktop/python/py2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 1394, in _get_socket
    sock_info = self.sockets.popleft()
IndexError: pop from an empty deque

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Gu/Desktop/python/py2.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(cluster.list_database_names())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 2037, in list_database_names
    for doc in self.list_databases(session, nameOnly=True)]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 2018, in list_databases
    res = admin._retryable_read_command(cmd, session=session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/database.py", line 770, in _retryable_read_command
    return self.__client._retryable_read(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1518, in _retryable_read
    with self._secondaryok_for_server(
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 117, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1371, in _secondaryok_for_server
    with self._get_socket(server, session) as sock_info:
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 117, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1308, in _get_socket
    with server.get_socket(
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 117, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 1331, in get_socket
    sock_info = self._get_socket(all_credentials)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 1397, in _get_socket
    sock_info = self.connect(all_credentials)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 1297, in connect
    sock_info.check_auth(all_credentials)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 820, in check_auth
    self.authenticate(credentials)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 837, in authenticate
    auth.authenticate(credentials, self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/auth.py", line 672, in authenticate
    auth_func(credentials, sock_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/auth.py", line 590, in _authenticate_default
    return _authenticate_scram(credentials, sock_info, 'SCRAM-SHA-1')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/auth.py", line 333, in _authenticate_scram
    res = sock_info.command(source, cmd)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 710, in command
    return command(self, dbname, spec, secondary_ok,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/network.py", line 158, in command
    helpers._check_command_response(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/helpers.py", line 167, in _check_command_response
    raise OperationFailure(errmsg, code, response, max_wire_version)
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: bad auth : Authentication failed., full error: {'ok': 0, 'errmsg': 'bad auth : Authentication failed.', 'code': 8000, 'codeName': 'AtlasError'}
Gu@21emashmore21-971 Desktop % /usr/local/bin/python /Users/Gu/Desktop/python/py2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 1394, in _get_socket
    sock_info = self.sockets.popleft()
IndexError: pop from an empty deque

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Gu/Desktop/python/py2.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(cluster.list_database_names())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 2037, in list_database_names
    for doc in self.list_databases(session, nameOnly=True)]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 2018, in list_databases
    res = admin._retryable_read_command(cmd, session=session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/database.py", line 770, in _retryable_read_command
    return self.__client._retryable_read(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1518, in _retryable_read
    with self._secondaryok_for_server(
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 117, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1371, in _secondaryok_for_server
    with self._get_socket(server, session) as sock_info:
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 117, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1308, in _get_socket
    with server.get_socket(
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 117, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 1331, in get_socket
    sock_info = self._get_socket(all_credentials)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 1397, in _get_socket
    sock_info = self.connect(all_credentials)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 1297, in connect
    sock_info.check_auth(all_credentials)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 820, in check_auth
    self.authenticate(credentials)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 837, in authenticate
    auth.authenticate(credentials, self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/auth.py", line 672, in authenticate
    auth_func(credentials, sock_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/auth.py", line 590, in _authenticate_default
    return _authenticate_scram(credentials, sock_info, 'SCRAM-SHA-1')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/auth.py", line 333, in _authenticate_scram
    res = sock_info.command(source, cmd)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 710, in command
    return command(self, dbname, spec, secondary_ok,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/network.py", line 158, in command
    helpers._check_command_response(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/helpers.py", line 167, in _check_command_response
    raise OperationFailure(errmsg, code, response, max_wire_version)
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: bad auth : Authentication failed., full error: {'ok': 0, 'errmsg': 'bad auth : Authentication failed.', 'code': 8000, 'codeName': 'AtlasError'}
Gu@21emashmore21-971 Desktop % /usr/local/bin/python /Users/Gu/Desktop/python/py2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 1394, in _get_socket
    sock_info = self.sockets.popleft()
IndexError: pop from an empty deque

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Gu/Desktop/python/py2.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(cluster.list_database_names())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 2037, in list_database_names
    for doc in self.list_databases(session, nameOnly=True)]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 2018, in list_databases
    res = admin._retryable_read_command(cmd, session=session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/database.py", line 770, in _retryable_read_command
    return self.__client._retryable_read(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1518, in _retryable_read
    with self._secondaryok_for_server(
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 117, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1371, in _secondaryok_for_server
    with self._get_socket(server, session) as sock_info:
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 117, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1308, in _get_socket
    with server.get_socket(
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 117, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 1331, in get_socket
    sock_info = self._get_socket(all_credentials)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 1397, in _get_socket
    sock_info = self.connect(all_credentials)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 1297, in connect
    sock_info.check_auth(all_credentials)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 820, in check_auth
    self.authenticate(credentials)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 837, in authenticate
    auth.authenticate(credentials, self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/auth.py", line 672, in authenticate
    auth_func(credentials, sock_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/auth.py", line 590, in _authenticate_default
    return
    with server.get_socket(
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 117, in __enter__

    raise OperationFailure(errmsg, code, response, max_wire_version)
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: bad auth : Authentication failed., full error: {'ok': 0, 'errmsg': 'bad auth : Authentication failed.', 'code': 8000, 'codeName': 'AtlasError'}
Gu@21emashmore21-971 Desktop %
```

Comment: Looks like your username/password is incorrect- can you double check this? If your pasword starts with a special char, try just putting it as is in the string eg. "gabriel:!password"